# VS 2019 Metadata Not Found and Value Can't Be Null Errors

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

Building a cross-platform App with Xamarin Forms (Most Recent Version).

These are my errors:

1. Metadata file 'C:\Users\sethb\source\repos\App\App\App\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ref\App.dll' could not be found. On File CSC, Line 1.
2. Value Cannot be null on File NewTicket.xaml, Line 1.

I have tried many solutions to solve this problem, such as:

1. Updating my Nuget Packages (including Xamarin and the Net Standard Library).
2. Updating Visual Studio 2019.
3. Various combinations of clean, empty bin/obj/nugget cache, restart app, build individual solutions, re-build entire project.
4. Comment out the Xamarin code I was working on when this error occurred.
5. Adjusting Configuration Manager for different platforms / build / deploy combinations
6. Uninstall and re-install the Net Standard Library.
7. I even tried deleting the offending page and re-building it from scratch.

Obviously, the core issue for problem #1 is that key files aren't making it into my netstandard2.0 file, but I have no idea why. Hopefully, solving that will also fix the "Value Cannot be Null" error.

I have noticed when I look up "NETStandard.Library" in my list of installed apps, the arrow symbol marking it as installed doesn't pop up. But when I click on it, it says version 2.0.3 is already installed. Strange.

I think the issue is deeper in the build order of my Project, but I'll add in the pages I was working on when this error occurred. Maybe you will find something I have missed.

Let me know if there's anything else I can provide on my end to help resolve this problem. I can't launch my emulators until this is fixed. Client is waiting on their new app and I'm dead in the proverbial water.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using App.Classes;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using App.Tickets_Module;
using App.Dashboard_Module;
using App.PO_Module;

namespace App.Tickets_Module
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewTicket : ContentPage
    {
        public List<Company> CompanyNames { get; set; }
        public string Client_Name = null;
        public int Client_Index;
        public string Client_Id = null;
        public string NewTicketPriority = null;

        public NewTicket()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            /*
            * CONSIDER: adding in a web link so they can click the ticket and go to Bento.
            */

            string email = App.UserEmail;

            //New Company List
            List<Company> CompanyNames = new List<Company>();

            //Send Open Ticket API Query
            NewTicketAsync(email, CompanyNames);

        }

        //Check for empty fields...
        private async void SendNewTicket(string email, string CheckTitle, string CheckPhone, string CheckDescription, string ClientId, string TicketPriority)
        {
            //Get Client Id
            //Client_Id = CompanyNames[Client_Index].Id;

            string Email = email;
            string Pass = LoadAPIKey().Result;
            string TicketClient = Client_Name;
            string TicketClientId = ClientId;
            string TicketPhone = CheckPhone;
            string ThisPriority = TicketPriority;

            //Add Backslashes
            string TicketTitle = CheckTitle;
            TicketTitle = TicketTitle.Replace("'", "''");

            string TicketDescription = CheckDescription;
            TicketDescription = TicketDescription.Replace("'", "''");

            //POST URL BELOW
            string url = "https://domain/tickets/new_ticket_sub.php?";

            //POST REQUEST
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {

                //JSON Content
                string content = "{'" + Email + "',*&'" + Pass + "',*&'" + TicketClient
                    + "',*&'" + TicketTitle + "',*&'" + TicketPhone  
                    + "',*&'" + TicketDescription + "',*&'"+ TicketClientId + "',*&'" + ThisPriority + "'}";

                //Prep JSON Message
                var JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
                var POSTdata = new StringContent(JSON.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                POSTdata.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                //Send JSON Message
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, POSTdata);

                var status = response.StatusCode.ToString();

                //Await Response
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                //Convert JSON Object into Usable Array
                var message = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestMessage>(responseString)).Message;

                if (message == "Email Not Found.")
                {
                    //New Response
                    string newMessage = "Email does not exist. Please register a bento account for this email address.";

                    //Print Response
                    restMessage.Text = newMessage;
                    restMessage.IsVisible = true;
                }
                else if (message == "Connection Failed.")
                {
                    //New Response
                    string newMessage = "Connection failed. Please contact support.";

                    //Print Response
                    restMessage.Text = newMessage;
                    restMessage.IsVisible = true;

                }
                else if (message == "API Login Error.")
                {
                    //New Response
                    string newMessage = "Internal key failure, please contact support.";

                    //Print Response
                    restMessage.Text = newMessage;
                    restMessage.IsVisible = true;

                }
                else if (message == "Submission Failed.")
                {
                    //New Response
                    string newMessage = "Internal ticket error, please contact support.";

                    //Print Response
                    restMessage.Text = newMessage;
                    restMessage.IsVisible = true;

                }
                else if (message == "Submission Succeeded.")
                {
                    //Send user to Dashboard
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new TicketsPage());

                }


            }
        }

        private async void NewTicketAsync(string email, List<Company> CompanyNames)
        {
            string Email = email;
            string Pass = LoadAPIKey().Result;

            //POST URL BELOW
            string url = "https://domain/tickets/new_ticket_page.php?";

            //POST REQUEST
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {

                //JSON Content
                string content = "{'" + Email + "','" + Pass + "'}";

                //Prep JSON Message
                var JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
                var POSTdata = new StringContent(JSON.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                POSTdata.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                //Send JSON Message
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, POSTdata);

                var status = response.StatusCode.ToString();

                //Await Response
                var responseJSON = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                //Convert JSON Object into Usable Array
                var ParsedTickets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Company>>(responseJSON);

                var length = ParsedTickets.Count();

                //Load array into individual Tickets
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    var companyModel = new Company
                    {
                        Company_Name = ParsedTickets[i].Company_Name,
                        Id = ParsedTickets[i].Id
                    };

                    CompanyNames.Add(companyModel);
                }

                //Load Ticket List
                //OpenTickets = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Ticket>>(responseJSON));

                //Load into new Tickets List
                NewTicketCompany.ItemsSource = CompanyNames;

            }
        }
        private async Task<string> LoadAPIKey()
        {
            string api_key = "";

            //Load API KEY
            try
            {
                api_key = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("api_key");

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.

            }

            return api_key;

        }

        private void NewTicketCompany_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Picker NewTicketCompany = sender as Picker;
            int selectedIndex = NewTicketCompany.SelectedIndex;

            Client_Name = NewTicketCompany.Items[selectedIndex];

        }

        private void SubmitNewTicket_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string CheckTitle = NewTicketTitle.Text;
            string CheckPhone = NewTicketPhone.Text;
            string CheckDescription = NewTicketDescription.Text;
            string ClientId = ThisClientId.Text;
            string TicketPriority = NewTicketPriority;

            if (Client_Name == null || CheckTitle == null || CheckPhone == null || CheckDescription == null || ClientId == null)
            {
                restMessage.Text = "Please fill out all form fields";
               
            }
            else
            {

                string email = App.UserEmail;
                SendNewTicket(email, CheckTitle, CheckPhone, CheckDescription, ClientId, TicketPriority);
            }
        }


        //NAVIGATION METHODS
        private void Home_link_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Dashboard());
        }

        private void User_profile_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new User());
        }

        private void Clients_profile_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Clients());
        }

        private void Tickets_list_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new TicketsPage());
        }

        private void Orders_list_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new OrdersPage());
        }

/*        private void TicketPriorityPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = (Picker)sender;
            int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

            if (selectedIndex != -1)
            {
                NewTicketPriority = (string)picker.ItemsSource[selectedIndex];
            }
        }
*/
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have it backwards.  If there is a problem in your XAML file, it can't build the dll, which creates the App.dll file

Comment: That was a huge help, Jason, thank you for the clarification. It's a lot easier to find bugs when you're looking in the right place!